# SSMS 2014 Only Allow Execute F5 if Text Selected

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

Update: Would like something that everyone can use, not just admin.

I tried to find if this question has already been asked before this post. In SSMS 2014, is there an option to only allow query execution if any text has been selected?

If none is selected, F5 and/or the execution button should be disabled. Thank you!

Comment: You probably could achieve it changing default key bindings inside SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my brief research, if user (like myself) who cannot run `RAISERROR` with severity level 20 or above, I am using `SET NOEXEC ON` and `SET NOEXEC OFF` in the very top and bottom. Then develop your script inbetween those two statements.

The downside is that there are two statements to add at 2 different locations. Also, if your script requires the use of `SET NOEXEC`, then this might not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have this snippet that I sometimes include at the top of my queries:

```
raiserror('Highlight something and tell me what you''d like to do.', 20, -1) with log
```

Per the Microsoft Connect page titled, *[Add an Execute Selected Text Only to SQL Server Management Studio](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/669159/add-an-execute-selected-text-only-to-sql-server-management-studio)*:

> ...We are considering adding this as a text-editor option for an
>   upcoming release. I have no way to mark it as "added to backlog", so
>   I'm resolving it as "Won't Fix". It's there though...
>
> Cheers
>   -Sam Hughes

That was in 2011. If there is a way to do this I suspect it would be using Redgate. I'm not a redgate guru but I know that, for example, SQL Prompt will throw a warning before letting you do a DELETE or UPDATE without a WHERE clause. That's where I'd start.

Comment: I put the below statement at the very top of my SQL script but when I clicked Execute without highlighting anything, the whole script still ran.

`raiserror('Highlight something', 18, -1)`

I do not have admin right to run `raiserror` with `with log`.

Comment: Odd - I never considered how this would work if someone did not have rights to run `raiserror`. That's a dealbreaker - I don't know any way around that. Again - I'm confident that Redgate has something for this kind of thing.

Comment: I do have right to run `RAISERROR`, just not with severity of 19 or above, which will terminate the current connection and, therefore, preventing the rest of the script from running.